# PHP foreach only returns first [0] of nested array

Tags: php, json, object, multidimensional-array

I have an object like below, with arrays nested in each other.
I use foreach loops to loop through the first and second level of the arrays.

```
array (
   'totalHits' => 500,
   'total'     => 845,
   'hits' =>
   array (
       0 => array (
              'url' => 'www.someurl.com',
              'id'  => '11',
       ),
       1 => array (
              'url' => 'www.differenturl.com',
              'id'  => '22',
       ),
 );
```

I am trying to get keys and values from all the arrays nested in 'hits', but I only get the first one, hits[0]. What am I missing?

```html
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  
  $keywords  = $_POST['pixa_keyword'];      
  $api_key   = "my_hidden_api_key";
  $url    = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=".$api_key."&safesearch=true&q=".$keywords;
  $json   = file_get_contents($url);
  
  
 }
 
 
?>

<body>
 

<form action="#" method="post">
 <input name="pixa_keyword" id="cms_pixaSearchKeywords2" type="text" value="">  
 <input name="submit_pixa_search" id="cms_pixaSearchBtn2" type="submit" value="search">
</form>


<div id="cms_displayPixaResults"></div>
 
<?php 
 
 $pixa_feedback=[];
 
 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
  $pixa_feedback = json_decode($json);
 }
 

 foreach($pixa_feedback as $inner){
  // check type
  if(is_array($inner)){
   // iterate through nested array
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($inner[$i] as $key => $value){      
    echo $key . ": " . $value . " <br>";
    $i++;
   }
  }
 }
 
 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter variable isn't doing anything as your `foreach` will only iterate over `$inner[0]` and then stop. You need to add a third level of iteration:

```
foreach($pixa_feedback as $inner){
    // check type
    if(is_array($inner)){
        // iterate through nested array
        foreach ($inner as $values){
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                echo $key . ": " . $value . " <br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
url: www.someurl.com <br>id: 11 <br>
url: www.differenturl.com <br>id: 22 <br>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/r1Ogs)

Comment: Thanks so much - this works! This was the most specific answer thus I will flag this as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

You weren't looping through your array correctly
Try this:

```
$temp = array (
   'totalHits' => 500,
   'total'     => 845,
   'hits' =>
   array (
       0 => array (
              'url' => 'www.someurl.com',
              'id'  => '11',
       ),
       1 => array (
              'url' => 'www.differenturl.com',
              'id'  => '22',
       ),
 ));

foreach($temp["hits"] as $inner_arr){
     echo $inner_arr["url"];
     echo $inner_arr["id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `foreach` you do not need a counter variable. The loop-body will run for every item in the first "argument". Thus the inner loop (during the outer-loop's 3rd iteration) iterates over `array ('url' => 'www.someurl.com', 'id'  => '11')` and finishes afterwards.